# not navigate to template page in django chartjs?Django Version: 1.10.8 and Python Version: 3.6.3

Tags: python, django, chartjs-2.6.0

I am new in django, i need to develop chart based application i am creating line chart using chart.js library

**Django Version: 1.10.8** & 
**Python Version: 3.6.3**

i have install

> pip install django-chartjs

INSTALLED_APPS settings:

INSTALLED_APPS = ('chartjs',)

Create the HTML file

[image]

Create the view with labels and data definition
[image]

and also add urls.py file and static files. when i run this application it returns only json data but i want to display chart if any mistake my code.its not navigate to html page.

reference link
http://django-chartjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [        
    url(r'^line_chart/$', views.line_chart_json, name='line_chart_json'),
]
```

Comment: Show us your `urls.py` - have you added both your views to the URL configuration?

Comment: urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^line_chart/$', views.line_chart_json, name='line_chart_json'),   
]